# If every person between 15-60 had an immune system equal to the healthiest people, would this affect the spread of coronavirus?

Tags: immunology, virology, immune-system, epidemiology, coronavirus

Has anyone calculated the speed or breadth of the spread of something like coronavirus (or any cold, flu, airborne pathogen) based on how well the population can master the virus with their immune system? Just as a simple example, let's say you shortened the window of contagiousness by 2 days. Would that have a significant impact on the spread of the virus?

Comment: SE Biology is a question and answer site — not a discussion site or a site for floating ideas. It is concerned with the mechanisms of biological processes, not medical or social aspects of biology. For one of these reasons I think  that your question on the coronavirus outbreak is off-topic here. Question of a medical nature might be on-topic at SE Medical Sciences. Otherwise you are advised to consult more appropriate reputable sources for such information, some of which are listed [here](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4035/information-about-coronaviruses/4036#4036).